# Can't read object information from a binary file, Java

Tags: java, binaryfiles

I'm writing a program that saves information about a car within an object ArrayList. I want to be able save the information from the ArrayList into a binary file, then load and view that information at a later date.

I've gotten the saving function to work however, I can't get the program to read the file. I'm getting an:

> error at "cars = in.readObject();".

I've placed my code below, any help would be appreciated. (PS. I can't swap the ArrayList for anything else)

```
ArrayList<carClass> cars = new ArrayList<carClass>();

public void openFile(){
        cars = null;
      try {
         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("yareyare.ora");
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
         cars = () in.readObject();
         in.close();
         fileIn.close();
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
         i.printStackTrace();
         return;
        }
      }
```

Here's what i'm adding to the array if you are interested

```
                System.out.println("What is the make of the car?");
                String newMake = scan.next();
                System.out.println("What is the model of the car?");
                String newModel = scan.next();
                System.out.println("What year was the car produced?");
                String newYear = scan.next();
                System.out.println("How far has this car traveled?");
                String newOdometer = scan.next();
                cars.add(new Car(newMake, newModel, newYear, newOdometer));
```

Comment: When you get an exception or a compile-time error, it's helpful when you tell us what you're getting. "I get an error" is useless.

Comment: I've got an answer.

Comment: Post the entire error message and stack trace you are getting. Also post the your code that writes to file `yareyare.ora`.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert your object into a car object

```
cars = (Car)in.readObject();
```